# Node Package Manager Failing on Browserify Script

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

There are lots of moving parts for this question so I will post everything. I am running npm run build and I get the following:

[image]

Here is my build script in package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build":"browserify -d app/scripts/src/main.js -o app/scripts/dist/main.js" 
  },
  "browserify":{
    "transform":[
      "babelify",{"presets":["es2015"],"sourceMap":true}
    ]
  },
```

**app.js:**

```
class ChatApp {
  constructor() {
    console.log("Hello World")
  }
}
 export default ChatApp
```

**main.js:**

```
import ChatApp from './app'
new ChatApp()
```

Node version: 6.9.4

Browserify version: 14.3.0

**UPDATE:**

I updated it and still same result.

```
  "build":"browserify app/scripts/src/main.js -d -o app/scripts/dist/main.js"
```

This also does not work and gives the same error:

```
"build":"browserify app/scripts/src/main.js > app/scripts/dist/main.js -d -o"
```

Also this same result:

```
"build":"browserify app/scripts/src/main.js > app/scripts/dist/main.js"
```

**UPDATE: Running only the Browserify command from terminal**

```
browserify app/scripts/src/main.js app/scripts/dist/main.js -d -o 
TypeError: Path must be a string.
    at resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:15:19)
    at nr (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/module-deps/index.js:282:24)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:17:13
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: Try putting the `-d` *after* the entry file. The entry file(s) precede the options.

Comment: @cartant It already has -d

Comment: Yes. And it's in the wrong place.

Comment: See the update in the question. Same result

Comment: ? Is this a browserfiy bug that I need to report?

Comment: You don't have enough information to usefully report a bug - or for the question to be answerable. You need an error message - not just an exit code. Use `npm run build --verbose` or run the browserify command directly using `./node_modules/.bin/browserify app/scripts/src/main.js -d -o app/scripts/dist/main.js`

Comment: If I just run the Browserify command then it says "Path must be a string". See update.

Comment: Google says: https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify/issues/383

Comment: Try this change: `"browserify": {
    "transform": [
      [
        "babelify",
        {
          "presets": [
            "es2015"
          ],
          "sourceMap": true
        }
      ]
    ]
  },`

Comment: Thanks @MariaInesParnisari That worked! Please post it as an answer and I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your error and fixed it by changing the `browserify` section of your `package.json` file (note how there's a nested array).

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify -d app/scripts/src/main.js -o app/scripts/dist/main.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [ [  "babelify", { "presets": [ "es2015" ], "sourceMap": true } ] ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^7.3.0"
  }
}
```